MDX: COUNT DISTINCT strange aggregation
I have cube with Stores and SKUHierarchy of Company-Brand-SKU.
I have measure Distinct count of SKU over both dim.
If I try:
SELECT 
 [Measures].[SKUCount] ON COLUMNS, 
 [Stores].[Store].[Store] ON ROWS 
FROM [Cube] 

it return values.
If I try
SELECT 
 [Measures].[SKUCount] ON COLUMNS, 
 [SKUs].[SKUHierarchy].[Company] ON ROWS 
FROM [Cube] 

it return values also.
If I try combination:
SELECT
[Measures].[SKUCount] ON COLUMNS,
CROSSJOIN ([SKUs].[SKUHierarchy].[Company], [Stores].[Store].[Store]) ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]

It return all [Measures].[SKUCount] as (null).
Why it not return count of distinct SKUs for combinations of Company and Store.
